# Javascript method always returns same value

Tags: javascript

I have two methods in my class. One method randomizes values, another one returns those values in a string that represents CSS color. Yet after randomization it still returns same string all the time, even though values in created object are changed. Can you please explain why?

Here's jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/wpem1j9e/

```
function Color(r, g, b) {
    this.r = r;
    this.g = g;
    this.b = b;
    this.randomize = function(){
        this.r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
        this.g = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
        this.b = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
        return this;
    }
    this.toString = function(){
        var cssColor = "rgb(" + r + "%," + g + "%," + b + "%)";
        return cssColor;
    }
}
var color1 = new Color (1, 1, 1);
color1.randomize().toString(); // still returns "rgb(1%,1%,1%)";
```

Comment: You are missing the "this" in the toString function when calling the variables

Comment: yBrodsky is referring to where you are using `r`, `g`, and `b` in your `toString` method.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because in your toString function you are using `r`, `g` and `b` instead of `this.r`, `this.g` and `this.b`. The former are you constructor parameters.

Comment: Oh wow, I spent about an hour trying to figure it out! Embarrassing... Thank you! I'll accept your answer when time limit ends.

Answer (score 1):

```
function Color(r, g, b) {
this.r = r;
this.g = g;
this.b = b;
    this.randomize = function(){
        this.r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
        this.g = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
        this.b = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
        return this;
    }

    this.toString = function(){
    var cssColor = "rgb(" + this.r + "%," + this.g + "%," + this.b + "%)"; //new
        return cssColor;
    }
}
var color1 = new Color (1, 1, 1);
output = function () {
    var outputDiv = document.getElementById("output");
    outputDiv.innerHTML = outputDiv.innerHTML + "<br>" + color1.r + "   " + color1.g + "   " + "   " + color1.b + "<br>" + color1.toString() + "<br>";
}
output();
document.getElementById("input").onclick = function(){
    color1.randomize();
  output();
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You can alleviate a whole lot of confusion by just ditching the use of `this`. It provides no benefit here.

```js
function color(r, g, b) {
  var me = {
    randomize: function() {
      r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
      g = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
      b = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
      return me;
    },
    toString: function() {
      var cssColor = "rgb(" + r + "%," + g + "%," + b + "%)";
      return cssColor;
    }
  };

  return me;
}
var color1 = color(1, 1, 1);
console.log(color1.randomize().toString());
```